# stringr::str_replace() extracting signed numbers in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract: `-1960.85`

from:

```
">Return on Equity</span><!-- react-text: 141 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 142 -->(ttm)<!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label=\"KS_HELP_SUP_undefined\" data-reactid=\"143\"></sup></td><td class=\"Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)\" data-reactid=\"144\">-1,960.85%</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div data-reactid=\"145\"><h3 class=\""
```

I am using the following to extract it:

```
stringr::str_extract(loc, "[:punct:]\\d+\\.\\d+\\D")
```

Unfortunately, this thinks I am referring to the comma in 1,986.85 and cuts the `1` completely. I do not want the comma by the way. How can I use `str_extract()` (or any other method)  to get the desired output?

```
loc <- ">Return on Equity</span><!-- react-text: 141 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 142 -->(ttm)<!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label=\"KS_HELP_SUP_undefined\" data-reactid=\"143\"></sup></td><td class=\"Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)\" data-reactid=\"144\">-1,960.85%</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div data-reactid=\"145\"><h3 class=\""
```

Comment: If you want to extract data from HTML, then you should be using an HTML/XML parser and not regex.

Answer (score 1):

In the above example you can fix it by including `,` along with `digits` as [0-9,].

```
stringr::str_extract(loc, "[:punct:][0-9,]+\\.\\d+\\D")
#[1] "-1,960.85%"
```

Other option one can think of as:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(str_extract(loc, "[:punct:][0-9,]+\\.\\d+\\D"),",","")
#[1] "-1960.85%"
```

But, if your content if of type `html/xml` then as `@TimBiegeleisen` has suggested you should use suitable parser to parse text before analyzing it.